# linux android emulator not show in adb devices after restart adb server

Tags: android, linux, adb, emulation

I using android emulator in linux(Ubuntu16.04), The adb server seems not working normal.

```
root@ubuntu:~/santi/opengl# adb -P 15770 devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5770   device

root@ubuntu:~/santi/opengl# adb -P 15770 root
root@ubuntu:~/santi/opengl# adb -P 15770 kill-server
root@ubuntu:~/santi/opengl# adb -P 15770 devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 15770 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 

root@ubuntu:~/santi/opengl#
```

Thus the problem, when I restart adb server, the emulator not in adb devices again!  Only if I restart the emulator, it shows again in adb devices.

```
The ADB version: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32

adb devices
adb root
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

Comment: I'm using the same adb version. I didn't get any problem after running these commands. I can see my device[emulator] after 'adb devices'. Are you able to repro this everytime?

Comment: @GauravChauhan emm, this problem happends always now. Is that something because multi-user or multi adb server? Since I start a different adb server wtih different ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT for each emulator.

Comment: @GauravChauhan I checked out only one vm and one adb server happends yet and always.  Strange things is that, before days, same code same scripts works well !  Is that emulator or adb-server went wrong? Drive me crazy.

Comment: after seeing that you use 5680 port to start emulator, you might have missed this warning

"emulator: Requested console port 5680: Inferring adb port 5681.
emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5681) is outside the recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for the emulator. See -help-port for details."

Check this for more info[https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#howadbworks]

Comment: @GauravChauhan U are right buddy, seems the problem is start port. But ADB not give any WARNING about this in my case. So where can I find out the recommend range? Or just have to check the adb source code.

Comment: @GauravChauhan I found it in this [https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html), Thx buddy！

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable! Above problem was caused by the emulator specified start port. As I start emulator with command:

```
emulator -avd template -gpu mesa -no-window -port 5680
```

The above port if > 5680, then device wont show after restart adb server, otherwise port <= 5680 it shows and definitely shows okay!